# Duplicating Terrain Across Multiple Scenes in Unity 5.1.1

Tags: terrain, unity-game-engine

I am trying to duplicate terrain for multiple different scenes and alter the terrain slightly, such as the grass and trees. However, when doing so, making one change to one terrain changes the terrain on another scene. I am aware of why this happens and have tried multiple different things (such as duplicating the terrain data itself) to get this to work but nothing has seemed to work so far. I am using Unity 5.1.1. Is there any way I can get across this? Doing so would save a lot of time in reconstructing the terrain. I am also aware that questions like this have been posted on here, but none of the solutions have worked unfortunately. Any help thus would be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: when you duplicate the terrain and the data file, you have to assign it to the copy in the editor. to do so, open the terrain copy in editor and change the inspector view to debug mode. there you can assign the copied data. i have done so on many occasions.

Comment: Wow this is wonderful! Thank you so much, for some reason I never thought to go into debug mode to see what was going on. Everything works now. Thanks so much! @JinJi If you would like to, you can post it as  an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you duplicate the terrain and the data file, you have to assign it to the copy in the editor. to do so, open the terrain copy in editor and change the inspector view to debug mode. there you can assign the copied data.